# Approach on exploding components in swing?

Tags: java, swing, animation

I'm working on the old multi-threaded bouncing balls problem in swing.  I've got everything set up so far, but I'd like to add an explosion animation when two balls collide. I've got collision detection and I can display text where the collision took place, but I was wondering on the best modular approach to creating a small animation (for example, pixels exploding 360 degrees around the point, fading out over time)

Class structure:

Ball

```
public class Ball {

    private double x,y,dx,dy;
    private static final int XSIZE = 15;
    private static final int YSIZE = 15;

    public Ball(){
        // make x,y,dx,dy random
    }

    public int getX(){//}

    public int getY(){//}

    public Point position(){
        return new Point(x,y);
    }

    public void move(Rectangle2D bounds){
        //do movement (change x,y,dx,dy)
    }

    public Ellipse2D getShape(){
        return new Ellipse
    }

    public boolean collide(Ball other){
        if (this.position().distance(other.position()) < XSIZE)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

BallComponent

```
public class BallComponent extends JPanel {

    public ArrayList<Ball> balls = new ArrayList<Ball>(); 
    private ArrayList<Color> colors = new ArrayList<Color>(); 
    private ArrayList<Point> explosions = new ArrayList<Point>(); 
    Random rnd = new Random();
    private boolean exploding = false; 

    public void add(Ball b) {
        balls.add(b);
        colors.add(new Color(rnd.nextFloat(),rnd.nextFloat(),rnd.nextFloat()));
}


    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g); 
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g; 

        for(int i=0; i<balls.size(); i++){ 
            for(int j=0; j<i; j++){
                if (balls.get(i).collide(balls.get(j))){ 
                    exploding = true;
                    explosions.add(balls.get(i).position()); 
                    balls.remove(i); 
                    colors.remove(i); 
                    balls.remove(j); 
                    colors.remove(j);
                    return; 
                }
            }
            g2.setColor(colors.get(i));
            g2.fill(balls.get(i).getShape());
            if (exploding){
                for (Point p : explosions){
                    g2.drawString("boom", p.x, p.y);
                }

            }

        }
    }

    public void reset(){
        balls = new ArrayList<Ball>(); 
        colors = new ArrayList<Color>(); 
        explosions = new ArrayList<Point>(); 
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you must do is get program logic out of the painting method, here the `paintComponent` method. You have collision detection within this method, your removing logical items from collections from within this method, you're even returning out of the method before it has fully done its primary job -- which is drawing all the components.

Instead I suggest that you re-arrange your program more along M-V-C or Model-View-Controller lines where the state of the balls is held by the model classes, the game loop controlled by the controller class, where collision detection is done in the controller using the model's state, and where the GUI classes, the "view" holds no program logic whatsoever and simply displays the state of the model.